# Data driven test in selenium/eclipse. Workbook error?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am trying to extract input from a external xls file into a selenium test in eclipse. I'm following a tutorial but for some reason I'm getting an error at the line:

```
Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(fi);
```

I'm not sure why it's not working. Not that I'm sure why it should be working either though...
Please look at the [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/3vkcoc761/) for more info!

Comment: Could you add relevant code to the question and maybe a link to the tutorial you're following?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jxl your code is fine some thing like :

```
    File f = new File("inputSheets\\DataDrivenJXL.xls");
    Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(f);
```

but if you are using Apache POI you will have to do something like

```
if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xlsx")){
         Workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }

    else if(fileExtensionName.equals(".xls")){
         Workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
```